# How do I setup GA Content Experiment variations without URI attributes, but with segmented URI's?

Tags: google-analytics, expressionengine, ab-testing

I'm experimenting with GA's Content Experiments.

I want to track performance of differences on a product detail page for all products on a given website.

I use ExpressionEngine (written on CodeIgniter) to serve the pages. The URI's are in this format:

```
domain.com/product/{product_id}/{product_short_name}
```

The variations are:

```
domain.com/product-b/{product_id}/{product_short_name}
domain.com/product-c/{product_id}/{product_short_name}
```

where {product_id} and {product_short_name} are dynamic.

How do I setup the Experiment to test *all* products? Now, I can only to hard-code the entire URI (with product ID and short name), so the test is only ran for that one product.

To elaborate: GA seems to be forcing me to use URI's with parameters (domain.com/product?id={product_id}&short_name={product_short_name}) where it will recognise the attributes and add them to the variations URI's. This isn't possible when the parameters are in the form of segments.